# Android using OnTouch to Detect longClick positions

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Well my goal is to detect the position of a long Click i was so confused where to start but i tried to use OnTouch as it helps detecting the positions of a click i tried to make it run as a longClick  using timer but it won't work

```js
clickableObject.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(!hold)startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    hold=false;
                }
                while(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN&&System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime<=1500);
                if(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime>1500)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
/*
```

as when i click a short click it works and i want it to work only on longClick

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way:

```
clickableObject.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i want to detect the positions i know how to do that in a OnTouchListener but i can't do that onLongClick

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution 
i created the onTouchListener with a longClick Listener in OnTouch i only get the positions

in OnLongListener i use the values of positions

```js
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public void getClickPositions(View clickableObject, final ClickPositions clickPositions){
        clickableObject.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (clickPositions != null)
                        clickPositions.getLastCordination(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

public interface ClickPositions{void getLastCordination(float left,float top);}

public void showImageOptions(final View clickableObject, final ClickPositions clickPositions) {
        getClickPositions(clickableObject, new ClickPositions() {
            @Override
            public void getLastCordination(float left, float top) {
                x = left;
                y = top;
            }
        });
        clickableObject.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(x) + ",", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

then i only call the function showImageOption